# How to write more that one logical gates?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I need to write code with simple logical gates. How to assign one output to be next gate input?

Here is what I have tried:

```
 module logical_gates(a,b,c,d,e,f,x,x1,x2,x3,x4);
  input a,b,c,d,e,f;
  output x,x1,x2,x3;

  wire a,b,c,d,e,f;
  wire x1,x2,x3,x4,x;

  assign x1=a&b;
  assign x2=e|f;
  assign x3=x1~|c;
  assign x4=x2~&d;
  assign x=x3^x4;
endmodule
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMfSn.png) is what i need to convert into code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there something wrong with your code? It seems to be fine (despite the fact that `x4` should also be defined as `output`). You can always describe your desired logic that way:

```
assign out = ~(~((a & b) | c) ^ ~(d & (e | f)));
```